# Finding file in which global variable is declared

Tags: c++, global-variables

I am trying to learn a fairly large open source codebase. In [this](https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA/blob/master/src/monster.cpp) file, a variable m is referenced many times without ever being declared (see line 819). So I figure it has to be a global variable.

However, this file includes roughly two dozen .h files. From what I understand, m could have been declared in any of these files. Is there any way I can determine which file declared it, or do I need to search through each .h file?

Is this the kind of thing you need a tool for? Does Eclipse have such a function?

Comment: In this file, it looks like 'm' is a member of the class represented by 'g'.  Hard to tell what 'g' is without digging further.  I'm guessing it's an instantiation of the "game" class, because "game.h" contains a variable "m" that is a map!

Comment: if `m` is really the global variable maybe you could search over compiled object files by grepping `nm *.o` and using pattern "B m$"

Comment: Yep - `game.h` defines a global instance of `game` called `g`, which contains a `map` named `m`.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, I present to you a case in what **not** to do when naming variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd download the source code and make a project from it in my IDE. I can then find the declaration via a context menu.

If there's a more elegant way I'd like to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the codebase downloaded locally, you could use grep: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Note that grep is a Unix based command, so depending on your shell it may not be available. If you're on Windows, FINDSTR (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) does something similar but isn't as flexible.

A quick example using grep would be something like this:

```
grep -l -R "some_string" /usr/local/SomeDirectory
```

Comment: the phrase 'm' occurs thousands of times in this guy's program.

Comment: I noticed that. That makes it particularly difficult, so either he will have to manually search for the original definition or figure out some sort of regex that will work well with grep. Honestly, it might just be easier to bite the bullet and search through those 2 dozen header files.